# How to get rows of a specific type matching a specific value?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get data from a table in my MySQL database.

```
  $linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 
  mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database."); 

 $search='flu';

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * From ProviderDxCptCodes WHERE CodeType='CPT'");

   $rows = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);
```

I want this query to show me all CPT codes matching the search string `flu`. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by: i want that for e.g I have search string flu so how can i get that value?

Comment: In which table and which field contain the information to search? for ex.: table DISEASE, column disease_name, then you would use that field to search for 'flu'

Comment: codeDescription is fieldin this table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
SELECT * From ProviderDxCptCodes WHERE CodeType='CPT' AND name LIKE '%flu%';
```

Comment: Please edit your post and submit all the different fields you have in your table and what information you want to fetch from it. We don't know what the variable $_searchItem is :S

Comment: is it ok but in table field is flu shake and i give here only flu it return 0 record i want that if it match any word or character like that it display

Comment: Okay, think I understand what you mean then, use LIKE as it has been mentioned here LIKE'%flu%' means fetch record that contains whatever flu whatever. So as long as the field contains flu it should return the record.

Comment: $query = mysql_query("SELECT * From DxCptCodesMaster WHERE CodeDescription='%".mysql_real_escape_string($flu)."%'");
 like this

Answer (score 0):

```
$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host."); 
  mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database."); 


  $flu = "CPT";

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * From ProviderDxCptCodes WHERE CodeType='%".mysql_real_escape_string($flu)."%'");

   $rows = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $rows[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: i am just getting empty rows when i run querry $flu="flu" and in table filed is flu shak

Comment: I edited my code to get your "flu" if present ANYWHERE in the entry. Just added '%'... is it good now?

Comment: @janialmani u are being very ambiguous. Where did the `456-465` suddenly come from? Please rephrase your question as follows:

1. What is the current database structure? (table name, columns and type)

2. What do you want to retrieve. (column name and table name)

3. Conditions to retrieve them.